# How to handle photos being uploaded at full resolution?

Tags: silverstripe

We have an issue where a client is trying to upload a full res photo, it is saying the file size is 2MB in the Mac finder window, however when opening in photoshop it is saying it is 60MB... As you can see it is full res, 5000 x 3700 pxs (approx)

[image]

When uploaded in the backend it shows broken in the image preview, but it is showing on the front end..

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this? What is the best way to handle/deal with this apart from getting the client to resize all the photos themselves?

Comment: I would try to increase memory_limit in php.ini for GD - you use that?

Answer (score 3):

ifusion, try [heyday's optimisedimage module](https://github.com/heyday/silverstripe-optimisedimage). We've used it to prevent this type of thing in the past.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try.